# Bash Script terminates when shell terminal is closed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, terminal

I'm able to successfully run the script below from a terminal in ubuntu 14.04.  However, when I close the terminal the vlc process also terminates which I don't want.  I've tried using "&" so that it runs in the background, but to no avail (script.sh &).  Any suggestions on how to run the script below so that if the terminal is closed, the vlc process does not terminate?  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
vlc --extraintf telnet localhost 4212 --vlm-conf /home/test/Videos/temp.vlm
```

Comment: try using nohup

Comment: I tried the following command but it didn't achieve what was desired: nohup temp.sh &

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) to open "virtual consoles" within a session.

- To install Screen: `sudo apt-get install screen`
- To start a new session: `screen`
- To disconnect from a session: Press and release together CTRL+A, followed by D.
- To get a list of current active sessions: `screen -ls`
- To reattach to a session: `screen -r <SESSION ID>`
- To start a named session: `screen -S <SESSION NAME>`
- To reattach to a named session: `screen -r <SESSION NAME>`

Comment: screen solved the issue.  Just curious and for the purpose of fully understanding, I never had any issues in using "&" with my bash scripts.  I've always been able to close the terminal and the script would continue to run.   Any reason why "&" would not work with the bash script in my post?  Is vlc a special process?  Thanks.